# How can we insert and retrieve back several data in different data types into an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I want to add a structure to an array and get the data back to the structure when i need it.Is there any way of doing it ?

```
char Memory[20000];

struct block
{
    size_t size;
    t_block next;
    t_block prev;
    int free;
    char data[1];
    void *ptr;

};

struct block aaa;
Memory[0]=(char) a;
```

This wont work

Answer (score 1):

What I am going to show, just answers your question, but it is a wrong way to do it. Pointers within your struct makes it even worse, since you cannot add something like assignment operator like in C++. 
So, you have to be ** extremely very ** careful with memory 'ptr' is pointing to.

```
struct block
{
    size_t size;
    t_block next;
    t_block prev;
    int free;
    char data[1]; // <= does it make sense ?
    void *ptr;

};

char Memory[sizeof(struct block) * 1000]; // 1000 is some random number I have picked, but
                                          // you have to multiply it with sizeof(struct)
                                          // so as not to access memory out of array bounds
struct block aaa = {1, /* some thing */ , /* some thing*/, 0, /* some thing*/, /*some thing */};

char* mem_ptr = &Memory[0];
// Storing
memcpy(mem_ptr, &aaa, sizeof(struct block));
mem_ptr += sizeof(struct block);

// Accessing
char* acc_ptr = &Memory[0];
struct block* abb = acc_ptr;
int i = abb->size;
```

Take extra care to make sure what is being pointed by 'ptr' is valid when you take it out of the array and dereference it (after casting ofcourse).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I know, I have mentioned that as well. Please go ahead and show the right way.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Ah..now I see where I completely messed up. Fixed it. Forgot that I created a char array :P